# Calling a non const function on a const instance in C++, is that possible?

Tags: c++, constants

I've got this following piece of code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Foo {
 public:
  void print() { cout << "hello\n"; }
}
  ;

Foo get_foo() {
  Foo f;

  return f;
}
int main()
{
   // If I get rid of this "const", then the error goes away
   const Foo f = get_foo();

  f.print();

  return 0;

}
```

When I compiled this, it gave me this error

```
test.cc:21:11: error: passing ‘const Foo’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]                                
  f.print();
```

I tried removing the "const" in f's declaration, then the code would compile.

But I don't understand the restriction. 
Can someone explain this?
How do I call "print()" without removing "const" from the declaration of the field?

Edit: The "Foo" class added above is purely for demonstrative purpose. In my real code, I can't edit the class, but the reason I want to make "f" const is for code-style/safety reason.

Comment: You cannot call non-`const` member functions on a `const` object. Make `print()` a `const` member function.

Comment: Mark `print()` as `const`

Comment: What if I dont have access to the Foo's class?

Comment: Why do you want to make `f const`? What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: for safety/code style reason. if soemthing is not going to change, then it should be const, no?

Comment: To address your edit: you can't. It doesn't make sense "for code-style/safety reasons". You can `const_cast` it but I don't recommend that. Just leave it as is. I know it's frustrating when you are using a function which _should_ be `const` but isn't

Comment: Only `const` methods can be called for a `const` object. For more information and a more detailed explanation see your C++ book.

Comment: @One Two Three  Just declare the function like void print() const { cout << "hello\n"; }

Comment: `void print() const { cout << "hello\n"; }`

Comment: @Tas I actually _would_ recommend `const_cast` because then you are explicitly marking your intent. It's a good way of saying to the next programmer "I am intentionally circumventing the constness here because I have reviewed the situation and know what I'm doing" (of course a comment to the effect that print should have been const would help too).

Comment: What if you update to a new version of the library and `print` does start to modify the object? I do see what you're saying though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The "Foo" class added above is purely for demonstrative purpose. In my real code, I can't edit the class, but the reason I want to make "f" const is for code-style/safety reason.

Since

```
void print() { cout << "hello\n"; }
```

isn't declared as `const` member function of `Foo` and you can't change that, you'll have to swallow that poor design, and access the `print()` function through a non `const` instance or reference.

To do that would need that `print()` is declared in the `Foo` class like

```
void print() const { cout << "hello\n"; }
          // ^^^^^
```

---

I agree that the better *code style* would be to allow calling the `print()` function using a `const` instance of `Foo`.

But as you mentioned, if you can't change that, there's no way beyond using an explicit cast:

```
const_cast<Foo&>(f).print();
```

Anyways that won't add additional *"safety"* vs a simple call:

```
int main()
{
    Foo f = get_foo();    
    f.print();    
}
```

Comment: There's no additional safety with the badly declared `print()` method. But using `const_cast` to use a `const` object with a _should-be-const_ method, means the `const` object is at least protected for any other methods it may call.

Comment: @Craig I don't get your concerns. Can you elaborate more please?

Comment: You said "_Anyways that won't add additional "safety" vs a simple call_" which is incorrect in a more general case. You seem to be advocating don't bother declaring as `const` because the method you're calling isn't a `const` method. But that's a narrow perspective because usually there's a  bigger picture involved and ***other methods*** some of which may be _correctly_ const-qualified.

Comment: @Craig You probably misunderstood my sentence there. I meant using that weird `const_cast` won't add any _"safety"_ in that particular situation. Or do you think it does?

Comment: No, I understand fully. I'm  pointing out to you that your failure to clarify makes a part of your answer misleading. Personally I think if you have to call non-const methods, you should probably make a copy; because the lack of compiler guarantee means you can't be certain of future versions of an implementation.

Comment: @Craig `const_cast`ing or calling from a non `const` copy, won't heal the substantial design injuries!

Comment: That should go without saying. Non-mutating methods _should be_ const qualified! OP doesn't explain why the existing declaration "cannot be fixed". But making a copy _does_ avoid the possibility of undefined behaviour if a previously non-mutating method called with a const_cast becomes mutating.

Comment: Wait, I have a question. The ore I look at it , the more I get confused.  So in `const_cast<Foo&>(f).print()` you're casting the `function`, not the the field `f`, right?

Comment: @OneTwoThree You're casting `f` (the object) to temporarily remove the const qualifier. Note you're keeping the same reference, so it's efficient. But if the function `print()` performs a mutation of `f` you expose yourself to undefined behaviour. The ***risk*** is that even if the current version of `print()` doesn't perform a mutation, a future version could, and there'd be no compiler error to report that mistake.